# Python build ignores yaml file although it is specified in Manifest.in

Tags: python, build, yaml, manifest

I'm currently trying to create a package out of my project unfortunately a yaml file that contains some meta information is ignored.

The file is in mypackage/resources/about.yaml

Any ideas ?

Here my MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include mypackage *.py
recursive-include mypackage *.pickle
recursive-include mypackage *.yaml
include mypackage/resources/about.yaml
include README.md
include requirements.txt
include dependency_links.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay solved myself. For some reason it is ignored if you put it in the Manifest file. Therefore I had to add this in my setup.py:

```
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'': ['resource/*.yaml']}
```

Of course I removed

```
recursive-include mypackage *.yaml
include mypackage/resources/about.yaml
```

from my MANIFEST file as it wasn't required anymore.

Hope this can help if someone is facing the same issue.